# How can flink reads newest data from kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

Now, in my scenario, flink reads newest data from kafka everytime. 
For example，
kafka products：

log1

log2

log3

When read，only log3 is needed.

Kafka consumer API, seekToEnd() can do it.

Does FlinkKafkaConsumer have the same function?

Comment: What do you mean with `log3`? Is this a topic or a data record?

Comment: This is a data record.

Answer (score 0):

Flink 1.3 has this function.

FlinkKafkaConsumer09 flinkKafkaConsumer09 = new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<>(properties.getProperty("topic"), new RowDeserializationSchema(properties.getProperty("separator"), resultType), properties);

flinkKafkaConsumer09.setStartFromLatest();